# Crash when extending and genericizing class SKSpriteNode in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, generics, sprite-kit

First, I have modified the file GameScene to add a new simple class MySprite as a subclass from SKSpriteNode to display a red rectangle. The code runs well:

```
import SpriteKit

class MySprite: SKSpriteNode {
    var scence: SKScene?

    init(theParent: SKScene) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(300, 300))
        self.position = CGPointMake(500, 500)
        scence = theParent
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {    
        var mySprite = MySprite(theParent: self)
        self.addChild(mySprite)
    }
}
```

Then I have converted that class to be a generic one as the following:

```
import SpriteKit

class MyBase {
    var property: Int = 0
}

class MyGame: MyBase {
    var id: Int = 0
}

class MySprite<B: MyBase>: SKSpriteNode {
    var scence: SKScene?

    init(theParent: SKScene) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(300, 300))
        self.position = CGPointMake(500, 500)
        scence = theParent // <- crash here EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        var mySprite = MySprite<MyGame>(theParent: self)
        self.addChild(mySprite)
    }
}
```

Compiled well but crashed when running with error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the line scence = theParent on the class MySprite. I have checked, the instant of MySprite has been created and looks normal.

Any idea about the problem and solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `class MySprite<B: MyBase>: SKSpriteNode` doesn;t make MySprite a subclass of MyBase. It just typealaises B to MyBase or a subclass (in this case MyGame) so you can do: var myProperty: B or func foo(x: B)

Comment: Just for your information: an Apple guy thought it may be a compiler bug but they have been still gathering more cases before confirming.

Comment: Have done a test in a playground and it crashes with no explaination. I think this is a bug.